# How to make my image reappear on hover after making it disappear with "visibility: hidden"?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I'm trying to build a card scheme where when you hover the mouse over the movie cover, some informations are displayed. The problem is: my star emoji doesn't reapear on hover.

I used this same `visibility: hidden/visible` with the center class, but with center-img it's not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">

.container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 424px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.fundo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 424px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#ff8a00,#da1b60);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.center-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.fundo:hover {
  transition: .4s ease;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.fundo:hover + .center {
  visibility: visible;
}

.fundo:hover + .center-img {
  visibility: visible;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <img class="fundo" src="https://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Classic-Movie-Posters-8.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre">
  <div class="center">10/10</div>
  <img class="center-img" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/samsung/161/white-medium-star_2b50.png"> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to see this shitty star to reapear on hover, if you guys can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hy Leo..your code need some enhancement...insted of use + (Adjacent Sibling Selector) you can use ~ (General sibling combinator)..Because it selects all elements that are siblings of fundo elements:...

Comment: Thanks, pal. Now I learned the lesson. Never gonna use this "+" selector again  haha

Comment: Great.......Leo

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch your selector from `.fundo:hover + .center-img` to `.fundo:hover ~ .center-img` because `<img class="center-img">` is not a direct sibling of `<img class="fundo">`.

The `~` selector will enable you to select any sibling of `<img class="fundo">` that has the class of `.center-img`.

---

**Using opacity transition**

[CodePen using opacity transition](https://codepen.io/yd-han/pen/rEJWdq?editors=1100)

```css
.center-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0; /* Add this */
}

.fundo:hover ~ .center-img { /* Change selector to this */
  transition: 1.2s ease; /* Add this */
  opacity: 1; /* Add this */
}
```

---

**Using visibility property**

[CodePen using visibility property](https://codepen.io/yd-han/pen/wLyoXe?editors=1100)

```css
.center-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.fundo:hover ~ .center-img { /* Change selector to this */
  visibility: visible;
}
```

---

**Solving the flicker effect when you hover over the star or score by using an overlay**

[CodePen implementation of overlay](https://codepen.io/yd-han/pen/QXQddZ?editors=1100)

The idea is to create an invisible overlay that will cover the entire movie image and apply the hover effects onto the overlay.

The flickering was occurring in your solution because the hover effects were placed on the movie image, which was behind the star and score on the z-axis.

Once your mouse hovered over either the star or score, the visibility effect was essentially being toggled because your mouse was hovering over the star/score instead of the movie image. This resulted in the hover effects on the star/score would be taken off. Once the effects were taken off and their visibility was hidden, you were back to hovering over the movie image. This cycle is what created the flickering effect.

```css
.fundo__overlay { /* Created new selector */
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 999; /* Give the overlay a higher stacking content */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Get it to match the movie image's dimensions */
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0; /* Used for hover transition */
}

/* Transferred hover effects */
.fundo__overlay:hover { /* Changed selector */
  transition: opacity .4s ease;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.fundo__overlay:hover ~ .center { /* Changed selector */
  visibility: visible;
}

.fundo__overlay:hover ~ .center-img { /* Changed selector */
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fundo__overlay"></div> <!-- Added new element -->
  <img class="fundo" src="https://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Classic-Movie-Posters-8.jpg" alt="Cinque Terre">
  <div class="center">10/10</div>
  <img class="center-img" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/160/samsung/161/white-medium-star_2b50.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't know about this difference between the "+" and "~" selectors. Thank you so much, very clear explanation. Now with the new code I have a glitch every time I hover over the star or the score numbers. What could it be? Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Comment: A possible solution would be to create a `<div>` where the width and height are 100% to the movie poster image and its `z-index` is above the other elements. You would then need to transfer the `:hover` effects onto the newly created `<div>` overlay. I will post the adjusted CSS on my main post.

Comment: Or put `pointer-events: none` on the divs `.center` and `center-img`. That way they don't interfere the hover state on `.fundo`.

Comment: I didn’t even know this existed. This makes it much simpler. Thanks!

Comment: Now everything works amazingly!! Thank you so much guys, learned a lot wih you.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 424px;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
}

.hover {
  visibility: hidden
}

.fundo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 424px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#ff8a00,#da1b60);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.center-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
}

.container:hover .fundo {
  transition: .2s ease;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.container:hover .hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```